# How to make my own splash screen

Tags: boot, plymouth

I'm trying to make a destro and I need to change the splash screen. I go to /usr/share but there is no images. help?

Answer (score 0):

http://www.noobslab.com/2013/05/mac-os-x-theme-for-ubuntu-1304-raring.html
i have seen something about splash screen here